# Filtering an array of objects using underscor functions JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of objects that looks like:

```
Object{
Name: Array[3]
[0]: 
 FirstName: John
 LastName : Smtih
 ClassID  : 123
[1]: 
 FirstName: Jane
 LastName : Doe
 ID       : 321
[2]:
 FirstName: John
 LastName : Smtih
 ClassID  : 456
}
```

I need to filter out the Array based on uniqueness, so no person with same firstname and last name and if there are two of the same people, then filter those same people with the classId i have chosen.

For example, if the there are two John Smith in the list, and if the current classId is 123 then my end result should look like

```
Object{
Name: Array[2]
0: 
 FirstName: John
 LastName : Smtih
 ClassID  : 123
1: 
 FirstName: Jane
 LastName : Doe
 ID       : 321

}
```

So basically, I need to check a array of objects to make sure two people dont have same first name and last name and if they do then i need to filter those people with the classID.

How can you filter with underscore functions?

Thanks

Comment: I dont think underscore would perform better than just two nested loops. You could have one parent for to check each element, and then filter with underscore if some has the same name.. but not really helpful

Comment: What in particular are you having problems with? Where are you stuck? You must have put *some* thought into solving the problem. I recommend to have a look at http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

Comment: oh, sorry about not putting my solution up, i tried using _.filter but it was absolute trash so I needed some help

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
var obj = {
   Name: [
      { 
         FirstName: "John",
         LastName : "Smtih",
         ClassID  : 123
      },
      { 
         FirstName: "Jane",
         LastName : "Doe",
         ClassID  : 321
      },
      { 
         FirstName: "John",
         LastName : "Smtih",
         ClassID  : 321
      }
   ]
};

obj.Name = _.uniq(obj.Name, function(item){
  return [item.FirstName, item.LastName].join()
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4) + "</pre>")
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
```

[_.uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) would be the most simple way to do so, specifying a unique string "FirstName, LastName".

Comment: This only looks at people's `LastName`, not `FirstName` + `LastName`. Also please explain how it works.

Comment: That's better... still missing the explanation though.

Answer (score -1):

```
 var uniqueCollection = _.uniq(array);
```

This example works only for arrays not for collections. In order to make your collection unique you need write custom logic in pure javascript.Underscore does not provide functionality that.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Did *you* try it? Care to explain how it works? Do you know what `_.collect` does?

Comment: This is from official docs for unique function "Produces a duplicate-free version of the array";

Comment: Did you actually try to apply that solution to the array in question? It does not work. It's basically the same as before. Blindly copying examples is not helpful.